# Getting Empty Replay from server while uploading huge tar file via tyk gateway

Tags: api, api-gateway, tyk

Hi I am trying to upload a 2G file via tyk-gateway with v3.2.2, by curl and I found the file is being uploaded successfully but the response from the server is seen in the packet capture but the tyk is responding back with an Empty reply from the Server.

> "Curl_http_done: called premature == 0 Empty reply from server
> Connection #0 to host left intact curl: (52) Empty reply from server"

Note that the tyk tested with and without docker in both the cases the response is the same

tyk.conf

> { “listen_address”: “”, “listen_port”: 8080, “secret”: “”,
> “template_path”: “/opt/tyk-gateway/templates”, “middleware_path”:
> “/opt/tyk-gateway/middleware”, “use_db_app_configs”: false,
> “app_path”: “/opt/tyk/apps/”, “storage”: { “type”: “redis”, “host”:
> “”, “port”: 6379, “username”: “”, “password”: “”, “database”: 0,
> “optimisation_max_idle”: 100 }, “enable_analytics”: true,
> “analytics_config”: { “type”: “csv”, “csv_dir”:
> “/var/log/tyk-gateway/metrics/”, “purge_delay”: 2 }, “health_check”: {
> “enable_health_checks”: false, “health_check_value_timeouts”: 60 },
> “optimisations_use_async_session_write”: true, “allow_master_keys”:
> false, “policies”: { “policy_source”: “file”, “policy_record_name”:
> “/var/config/default/tyk/policies/policies.json” }, “hash_keys”:
> false, “close_connections”: true, “allow_insecure_configs”: true,
> “global_session_lifetime”: 100, “force_global_session_lifetime”:
> false, “max_idle_connections_per_host”: 100, “http_server_options”: {
> “enable_websockets”:true } }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a timeout issue and there might be a couple of options that can resolve this outlined in the [gateway config](https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-oss-gateway/configuration/). To summarize:

- `close_connection` ​parameter is for User => Tyk. Default timeout is 120 seconds and is controlled via http_server_options.(read|write)_timeout
- `proxy_close_connection` parameter is for Tyk => Upstream. Default timeout is 30 seconds and can be overridden using `proxy_default_timeout` or the [Enforced Timeouts](https://tyk.io/docs/planning-for-production/ensure-high-availability/enforced-timeouts/) middleware.
- `max_conn_timeout` parameter limits length of keep-alive connection.